# Is is possible to disable source-maps in create-react-app without having to eject

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, source-maps

Was wondering was it possible to disable source-maps in create-react-app without having to eject. Guessing once you eject from create-react-app you can disable source-maps in webpack.

Comment: Thought these solution might be useful anyone else runs into this issue as I could not find any similar solutions on stackoverflow.


Have 2 initial solutions that I found to work.
1. adding GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=true into the build script in the package.json file.
2. adding GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false to the .env.production file also prevented source maps being added to my production build.


hope this is of some help to someone.

Answer (score 4):

Prepend your `build` script with `GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false`:

```
"build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. We can remove by adding a post build command like

```
yarn build && rm build/static/js/*.map && rm build/static/css/*.map
```

Answer (score 1):

As per [create-react-app doc](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration) you can create a .env file at the root of your project and add this:

```
GENERATE_SOURCEMAP = false
```

It will only remove source map for production build.